# Is it possible to use the $slice projection in a DESC order in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following find query:

```
        {
            "_id":ObjectId("1234567890")
        },
        {
            "responses":{
                "$slice":[0,10]
            }
        }
```

This will return the latest 10 responses, but I would like to return the last 10 responses. Is it possible to sort a slice in DESC order?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstand, but do you mean something like

```
{
    "responses":{
        "$slice" : -10
    }
}
```

? [According to the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/), that returns the last items in array.

Please note, however, that this isn't in `DESC` order in SQL-like terms: `$slice` works within a single document, and the order within arrays within that document can't be controlled by the query.

Comment: I want to start with the last set of 10 and then move towards the front of the list in increments of 10